# Format c# dateTime to local string format

Tags: c#, android, datetime, unity-game-engine

I have a DateTime C# object (in a Unity script, targeted for an Android device). I want to retrieve a string representation via .toString() (so w/o any special formatting parameter), which is supposed to deliver a short form like "10/5/2014 9.17 PM". If I now run it on an Android device with the locale set to e.g. German, just the time will be converted  correctly, while the date stays in US format (so "10/5/2014 21.17" instead of "5.10.2014 21.17").
Am I doing something wrong here, or maybe don't I understand the whole thing at all ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption about `DateTime.ToString` is correct. The following code prints 05.10.2014 13:26:36:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString());
```

I'd check what the value of `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString()` is in your environment and ensure that Unity sets it correctly. If it doesn't, you would have to do it yourself.

Comment: Or just simply `time.ToString(new CultureInfo("de-DE"))`

Comment: That will have the same output as above but it sounds like he wants to rely on the thread's culture being set correctly to output the date in the user's preferred format.

Comment: Right, it should be formatted according to the current locale.
One strange observation: when I put the following line right in front of the string formatting, it works correctly:

 `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;`

AFAIK CultureInfo.CurrentCulture should in principle return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, so the above statement wouldn't make much sense. But this way it works...strange.