# How to get client machine date format?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date

I want to get client machine date format, my application is hosted on US machine.

Hosting Server date format : MM/dd/yyyy
Local(Client) machine date format:  dd/MM/yyyy

I want to get dd/MM/yyyy format which is the format of the client machine.

I have used the following code but it returns server date format(MM/dd/yyyy) but I want client machine date format(Local).

```
DateTimeFormatInfo info = new DateTimeFormatInfo
{
    ShortDatePattern = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
};
```

Can anyone please tell how to get client machine date format(dd/MM/yyyy)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format c# dateTime to local string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205762/format-c-sharp-datetime-to-local-string-format)

Comment: I don't think the users local machine's date format is available to you unless your code is running on their machine, or you have that client send you their culture info, I guess

Comment: `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Request.UserLanguages(0)).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`?

Comment: If you know *both* (initial and desired) formats, then `ParseExact` and format back with `ToString()`: `string result = DateTime.ParseExact(source, initialFormat, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).ToString(desiredFormat);`

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed That assumes, there _is_ a `Request`.

Comment: Given a Server/Client scenario is this an ASP.Net question?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i only know about server date format(MM/dd/yyyy), client date format can be any thing.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC asp.net :

Frist put `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Request.UserLanguages.FirstOrDefault());`into `Application_BeginRequest`

if you don't have `Application_BeginRequest`. Please click `Global.asax`in your project.

add new function in MvcApplication class

`protected void Application_BeginRequest() {`

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo(Request.UserLanguages.FirstOrDefault());`
`}`

now , you could use format of DateTime.Now with client machine

Answer (score -1):

For Retrieving Client date format. I think java-script would be the best option

Try below code. I hope it will help.

```
getDateFormat(){
    // initialize date value "31st January 2019"
    var my_date = new Date(2019,0,31);
    console.log(my_date.toLocaleDateString());
    // Initialize variables
    var separator="";
    var first="";
    var second="";
    var third="";
    var date_parts = [];

    // get separator : "-", "/" or " ", format based on toLocaleDateString function        
    if (my_date.toLocaleDateString().split("-").length==3){
        separator = " - ";
        date_parts = my_date.toLocaleDateString().split("-");
    } 
    if (my_date.toLocaleDateString().split("/").length == 3) {
        separator = " / ";
        date_parts = my_date.toLocaleDateString().split("/");
    } 
    if (my_date.toLocaleDateString().split(" ").length == 3) {
        separator = " ";
        date_parts = my_date.toLocaleDateString().split(" ");
    } 

    // get first part        
    if (date_parts[0]==2019){
        first ="yyyy";
    } else if (date_parts[0] == 31){
        first = "dd";
    } else{
        if (date_parts[0].length<=2){
            first ="mm";
        }
        else{
            first="mmm";
        }
    }

    // get second part        
    if (date_parts[1] == 2019) {
        second = "yyyy";
    } else if (date_parts[1] == 31) {
        second = "dd";
    } else {
        if (date_parts[1].length <= 2) {
            second = "mm";
        }
        else {
            second = "mmm";
        }
    }

    // get third part        
    if (date_parts[2] == 2019) {
        third = "yyyy";
    } else if (date_parts[2] == 31) {
        third = "dd";
    } else {
        if (date_parts[2].length <= 2) {
            third = "mm";
        }
        else {
            third = "mmm";
        }
    }

    // assembly
    var format = first + separator + second + separator + third;
    console.log(format);
    return format;
}
```

Comment: How do you propose that we run the Javascript from C#?

Comment: Yes i can get it using javascript but trying to finding a way to get it from server side.